# Rails - what is the best way to create a unique ID based on the microtime the same as uniqueid() in PHP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In **Ruby on Rails**, what is the best way to create a `unique ID based on the micro time` the same as `uniqueid()` in **PHP**?

Comment: In Rails 5 or greater you can add `has_secure_token :my_secure_token` to your model. Just make sure you have a column name that correlates with `:my_secure_token`.

Comment: Why do you need it? You can probably use just SecureRandom https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html

Comment: You should edit your question to answer the six questions I give in "[Unique Random Identifiers](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Unique_Random_Identifiers)", as they will help you decide how best to generate unique identifiers.  For example, do these numbers have to be hard to guess? If not, why not just use sequentially assigned values (such as auto-incrementing rows if your database supports them)?

Comment: Why would you want to replicate `uniqueid`? Like most of the PHP stdlib its freaking horrible at its job. Use `SecureRandom#uuid` or the `pg_cryto` extension and `uuid` type columns if you are using Postgres.